# In hyperreal, does EVP imply IVP? Other way?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, nonstandard-analysis

So I define those two properties as ($\mathbb{R_H}$ denotes hyperreal numbers):

EVP: If $I$ is an interval and $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R_H}$, we say that $f$ has the extreme value property iff $f$ has its maximum value on that interval $I$. That is, $\forall a\leq b\in I$, $\exists x\in[a,b]\forall y\in[a,b]$ such that $f(y)\leq f(x)$.

IVP: If $I$ is an interval, and $f:I\rightarrow\mathbb{R_H}$, we say that $f$ has the intermediate value property iff whenever $a<b$ are points in $I$ and $f(a)< c<f(b)$, there is a $d$ between $a$ and $b$ such that $f(d)=c$.

My question is, in hyperreal set, does EVP imply IVP? How about the other way around? I suspect "no" for both of them but still cannot find a counter example. Cheers!

Comment: Are you assuming your functions to be standard? Internal? External?

Comment: @MikhailKatz: It's an internal function.

Comment: I think the internal definition principle should imply that if the implication is true over R it will be true over R* as well.

Comment: I'm not sure this question makes sense. You have a specific model, each statement is either true or false simply because of what the model is. Normally we ask questions like this in the context of the (abstract) theory of ordered fields (OF); i.e. the phrase "does EVP imply IVP" really means to ask if IVP is a consequence of OF+EVP.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: How if the function is an external function?

Comment: The transfer principle does not say anything at all about external functions.